# Use RSSBlockParser success block with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna use the RSSBlockParser with the new Swift programming language.

Everything works, expect of 'how to work with blocks'. For example the elementary call of the rss parser:

```
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://www.codebuddies.de/feed"))
    let parser = RSSParser()
    parser.parseRSSFeedForRequest(request, success: <#((AnyObject[]!) -> Void)?#>, failure: <#((NSError!) -> Void)?#>)
```

I hove no idea, how to replace the placeholder for success and failure.
Thanks for any help or links which I missed to find on my own googleing.

Thanks for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, closures are used in place of blocks.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_117

```
success: { (objects: AnyObject[]!) in
    // Do things with objects
}

error: { (error: NSError!) in
    // Do things with error
}
```